# Scraping with Beautiful results in jibberish

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website using BeautifulSoup4, however everything after the body tag is gibberish, and breaks the terminal. 
The website is tagged with utf-8 so I have tried decoding and different html parsers, including html.parser and lxml.

```
obsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read().decode('utf-8','ignore'), "html5lib")
print(bsObj.prettify())
```

Result:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
    <body>
 }zƲu}y┴(M։ʖO┬┌;R° ─H$D◆P⎼^▒&▒└⎻;\␍␍ (Q│P]]]U]]U£œ␉NG/?5˶ض&±├;ӗ/D&▒└⎻;·GW5Q߶/..(ڧ?ڗV*V┘┌[;≥⎻^N0T4ۓ┐'┴┘S7׏; њ#─K
```

The relevant lines in the website are :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="da" lang="da" dir="ltr" class="js"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: What is the address tyou are trying to scrape?

Comment: http://www.fdm.dk/bildatabasen/mazda/mazda3/15-100-hk/6-man-core-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns fine for me...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests
import html5lib


def get_data():

    url = 'http://www.fdm.dk/bildatabasen/mazda/mazda3/15-100-hk/6-man-core-2017'
    r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36"})
    html_bytes = r.text
    soup = bs4(html_bytes, 'html5lib')

    res = soup.find("body")
    print(res.prettify())

    return res

test1 = get_data()
```

returns

```
<body>
 <header id="header">
  <div id="logo-section-desktop">
   <div class="rowf">
    <div class="small-12 medium-3 large-3 columns">
     <a href="/" id="desktop-logo">
      FDM
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-9 large-9 columns">
     <ul class="top-navigation inline-list">
      <li>
       <a href="https://fdm.dk/alt-om-biler/vild-med-biler/motor">
        Motor
       </a>
      </li>
      ...
```

Comment: which library are you importing requests from?

Comment: requests.. it is a python builtin library.. `import requests`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you're getting compressed data from the website. Using the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), as johnashu does, will automatically decompress it for you. You could do this manually but that's a harder question.